# Whirlpool range burner gas flow too low- Is the nut inside the burner adjustable? Does it increase gas pressure?

Tags: repair, gas-stove

My front burner has low gas flow (pressure?) compared to the two back burners. The low flame setting is great, but when turning up the flame, it achieves maximum power at medium and no additional power from medium to high. The other burners put out more power. I have messed with the small screw adjuster in the burner knob but that isn’t helpful. Below is a picture of the interior burner- will this nut (golden color hex nut in the center of the picture) allow more gas pressure? Which direction do I turn? I didn’t experiment because I didn’t have an exact fitting socket wrench and so didn’t want to force it with pliers. [image: close up of burner where the gas comes out]

Answer (score 2):

No, that nut is just drilled to a particular jet size, this jet or orifice is designed to give s given flow rate for the gas and associated pressure.

My son bought a 2 ring gas appliance and it came with 2 sizes of jets. Based on whether it was to be supplied by the mains gas there is one size and if from a propane tank then it is another size.

The gas appliance manufacturers either sell you one with the correct jets for the gas you specify or like the one we bought you have to fit the correct jets.

If you fit the larger jet in error then you notice when the flame hits the ceiling :)

However, in your case the first thing i would check is to see if there is an inline valve that has been "played' with ie partially closed, or if a pressure reducer is failing etc

Comment: Could a partial clog(food spill) do what OP is saying?

Comment: I haven’t tried to clean out that part of the burner. I’ll investigate but assumed food didn’t make it there. 

As for the “inline valve” - I’ll try to investigate that too. I had trouble removing the top of the range as I removed the two front screws but just have missed something else that kept it from popping up. It’s a Whirlpool WGG755S0BS06 btw.

Comment: In-line valve in the supply pipe between meter and stove.

Comment: You can get little poker wires that will clean out the orifice. The wires come in different diameters for different orifaces, and may be in a set.

Comment: You may be able to clean it using the smallest sewing needle you have.

Comment: A sewing needle removed a tiny bit of gunk and that indeed solved the problem.